# Using SuperBuilder to extend parent class using Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, lombok, dto

I had a DTO that was using Lombok functionaliy as shown below.But now due to some requirement I had to extend my DTO to a parent class which looks like below.How can I do minimal change in my DTO to support that.I tried using @SuperBuilder annotation but it failed.

DTO Before:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class RequestMessage {
private final String name;
 }
```

Parent Class that needs to be extended

```
   @Data
   @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
   @JsonDeserialize(builder = MyDTO.Builder.class)
   public abstract class MyDTO implements Serializable {
   @JsonIgnore private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   protected String myAccountId;

   protected MyDTO() {}

   public static int hashCode(Object... objects) {
     return Arrays.deepHashCode(objects);
   }

   public static boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
    // implementation of equals method
   }

   public abstract String emitSerializedPayload() throws JsonProcessingException;

   @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
   protected abstract static class Builder<T extends MyDTO, B extends Builder<T, B>> {
   protected T dtoInstance;
   protected B builderInstance;

   public Builder() {
  dtoInstance = createDtoInstance();
  builderInstance = returnBuilderInstance();
}

protected abstract T createDtoInstance();

protected abstract B returnBuilderInstance();

public B myAccountId(String accountId) {
  dtoInstance.myAccountId = accountId;
  return builderInstance;
}

public T build() {
  return dtoInstance;
}
}
}
```

I tried to build RequestMessageClass manually and it works fine but there are lot of classes in my application and I dont want to change them manually, how can I change my existing RequestMessage class with annotations or some minimum change to get it working.

This is what I tried but I am getting compilation error when doing this

```
    RequestMessage.Builder().name(myName).myAccountId(myAcId).build();
```

What I tried is like shown below:

```
 @Getter
 @ToString
 @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
 @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
 @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
 public class RequestMessage extends MyDTO {
 private final String name;

 @Override
 public String emitSerializedPayload() throws JsonProcessingException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
}
```

Comment: You should try to add `@Builder` or `@SuperBuilder` annotation to your parent class as well

Comment: I did that @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true) but it din't work ,I updated the parent class.

Comment: You shouldn't mix lombok `@Builder` with static inner class Builder. In your case the easiest way will be refactor parent class and replace `Builder` class with `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)` annotation.

Comment: on removing the static inner class and replacing with superbuilder annotation like you said. It gives the error saying RequestMessage.Builder cannot be resolved to a type.Create class Builder in type RequestMessage in this line of code RequestMessage.Builder().name(myName).myAccountId(myAcId).build();

Comment: you should use `.builder()` instead of `.Builder()`

Comment: Its the same error if I use .builder() or .Builder().

Comment: I commented out inner static builder class in my parent class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't mix lombok `@Builder` with static inner Builder class. If it is possible to get rid of `Builder` class, the next code should work.

**RequestMessage**:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class RequestMessage extends MyDTO {
    private final String name;

    @Override
    public String emitSerializedPayload() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return null;
    }
    public RequestMessage(String myAccountId, String name) {
        super(myAccountId);
        this.name = name;
}
}
```

**MyDTO**:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class MyDTO implements Serializable {
    @JsonIgnore private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    protected String myAccountId;

    protected MyDTO() {}

    public MyDTO(String myAccountId) {
       this.myAccountId = myAccountId;
    }

    public static int hashCode(Object... objects) {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(objects);
    }

    public static boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // implementation of equals method
        return false;
    }
    public abstract String emitSerializedPayload() throws JsonProcessingException;
}
```

**Test**:

```
@Test
void name() {
    String myName = "myName";
    String myAccountId = "myAccountId";
    var request = RequestMessage.builder().name(myName).myAccountId(myAccountId).build();
    System.out.println("request = " + request);
    RequestMessage requestMessage = new RequestMessage(myAccountId, myName);
}
```

Comment: Ok I was trying to instantiate it with new i.e                                                        new RequestMessage.builder().name(myName).myAccountId(myAccountId).build()

Comment: Can't I use new??

Comment: Also what should be the difference between EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) and just EqualsAndHashCode.As previously I was just using EqualsAndHashCode. Soo can I continue using the same or should I do callSuper=true.

Comment: `new` keyword is not related to Builder pattern. If you want to use it you need do declare a constructor in parent class, and then use it (call `(super()`) in child constructor.

Comment: as per docs: lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = [call | skip | warn] (default: warn)
If set to call, lombok will generate calls to the superclass implementation of hashCode and equals if your class extends something. If set to skip no such calls are generated. The default behaviour is like skip, with an additional warning.

Comment: Ok I got the clear concept of lombok.equalsAndHashCode.I will accept the answer now just a last question So If I just use equalsAndHashCode it gives me this message Generating equals/hashCode implementation but without a call to superclass, even though this class does not extend java.lang.Object. If this is intentional, add '@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)' to your type.So should i change it to callSuper=false to keep it in sync with my previous DTO.

Comment: yes, correct. If it is set to `false` only field `name` will be used for generated equals/hashCode methods.